# Common Lisp function or idiom for creating a temporary file name?

Tags: common-lisp

Is there a Common Lisp function or typical way for creating a temporary file name or file?

Comment: Found this related link: https://bugs.launchpad.net/sbcl/+bug/393104

Answer (score 6):

Update since a few years have passed. There are two systems that can open a temporary file not previously mentioned, [cl-fad](http://weitz.de/cl-fad/#temporary-files) and [UIOP](http://www.cliki.net/uiop). They are both in quicklisp, and UIOP is part of ASDF3, which comes with most CL implementations now.

Comment: For my own project [GSLL](http://common-lisp.net/project/gsll), I have just replaced Osicat with UIOP, because apparently the latter works better on Windows.

Answer (score 3):

There is no function for that in common lisp. Allegro has [make-temp-file-name](http://ns2.franz.com/support/documentation/8.0/doc/operators/system/make-temp-file-name.htm), Emacs has [make-temp-file](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/info2www?(elisp)Unique%20File%20Names), clisp has [mkstemp](http://clisp.cons.org/impnotes/syscalls.html).

Answer (score 2):

See the [Osicat](http://common-lisp.net/project/osicat/) function [open-temporary-file](http://common-lisp.net/project/osicat/manual/html_node/Files-and-Symbolic-Links.html#Files-and-Symbolic-Links) and macro with-temporary-file.  This only creates a file and returns a stream, it does not provide a pathname, so it will only work where a stream is sufficient.  Osicat is in [Quicklisp](http://www.quicklisp.org/).

Comment: You can use [pathname](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/f_pn.htm) to get the pathname of a stream.

Comment: @billitch That is true, but I had in mind that the OP wanted to get a pathname without actually opening the file, given the phrasing of the question: "creating a temporary file name".